# Name autoscaling group created using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, aws-cloudformation, naming, autoscaling

I am creating an auto-scaling group using cloud formation script and want a particular name to be assigned to the group created. I've read that the value given to the "name" tag will be used for naming but aws appends the stack id as well to it. Is there a way to avoid that and just have a predefined name assigned to the group?

Comment: I don't think there is. To see if someone could help you though, what's the problem that you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: @Miles Need to use the 'UpdateAutoScalingGroup' API on the auto-scaling group created using CF template.
So thinking of a way to predefine the name.

Answer (score 3):

As with most resource creation CloudFormation will append the stack id to the name. It will not append it to the "Name" tag so you can use that and other tags to identify your AutoScale group.

You can also refer to the resource in your CloudFormation template by the name you originally assigned, the appended id will not be needed for that. For example:

```
    "ScalePolicy1": {
        "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
        "Properties": {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                "Ref": "MyAutoGroupName"
            }
        }
```

If you need to reference the Auto Scale group in other CloudFormation templates you can also use an output property in the creating template and give it a normal variable name that can be used like this:

```
  "Outputs": {
    "outAutoScaleName": {
      "Description": "Easy access name for my auto-scale group",
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "MyAutoGroupName"
      },
      "Export": {
        "Name": "ag-MyAutoGroupName"
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my case, the API to update auto-scaling group is currently within the application that is deployed using the same CF script. And the in-built aws update API requires the AS name passed to it as a parameter. So the tag value will not be helpful. Do you see a solution to achieve this?